# Unable to invoke Python from command line, SUSE Linux

Tags: python, suse

When I type "python" into the terminal I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 100, in search_function
    level=0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 2
    Description=Operations Management Suite agent
                                    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Here's the version information of my SUSE installation:

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try re-installing with `sudo apt-get remove python`, then install with `sudo apt-get install python`. Can you also tell me what python version you are using? If this does not work, then you can install linuxbrew and install python3.7 or python2.

Comment: Does SuSE hav sudo apt-get? I thought it just had Zypper, though I could be wrong. Zypper throws an error, too :(

Comment: can you check, i am not familiar with SuSE

Comment: Also, what do you plan to do with this server?

Comment: It's running an SAP HANA server. I wanted to run a python script that is supposed to verify the configuration is correct.

Comment: apt-get returns "command not found"

Comment: SuSE has not got apt. Careful with sap hana setups and software compliance.